How to Run CircleCI Job on Master Branch Only If a Specific Tag Is Present
I'm trying to configure my CircleCI pipeline to run a job only when both the following conditions are met:

The current branch is master
A specific tag (e.g., v1.0.0) is present.

I've used the filters in CircleCI, but I noticed that filters for branches and tags seem to apply an OR condition by default, meaning the job runs if either the branch is master or a tag is present, not both.
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_on_master_and_tag:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
            tags:
              only: /^v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/

How can I enforce this AND condition in CircleCI? Any suggestions or workarounds would be much appreciated!
Note: A possible workaround would be to add a check at the first step of the job and exit early if the branch is master but no tag is present. However, I don’t like this approach because it still triggers the job unnecessarily, even when the conditions aren't met. Ideally, I would prefer a solution that prevents the job from starting unless both the branch is master and a specific tag is present.

A Git tag in is a pointer to a specific commit; it's not related to a branch. You either push a tagged commit or you push a commit onto a branch. Git tags and branches are mutually exclusive.
